How to reuse a function in Next.js from getStaticProps and on the client to handle URL changes without reloading the page?
I'm working on a Next.js application where I need to manage dynamic content based on the URL. The function determineRegionSlug is centralized in a service file (service.ts) and is called from getStaticProps to pre-render the page with specific content. However, I also need to update that content dynamically on the client when the URL changes without reloading the page
My current setup:
service.ts - Contains the logic for determineRegionSlug.
service.setup.client.ts - Imports and exposes determineRegionSlug.
getStaticProps - Calls determineRegionSlug to calculate computedRegionSlug.
Page component (ListaSEO) - Needs to update content when the URL changes dynamically on the client.
Currently, determineRegionSlug runs on the server, but when the URL changes on the client, the content doesn’t update without a full page reload. How can I use this logic on the client to dynamically update the content based on URL changes?
Service.ts
export function determineRegionSlug(pathListaSeo: string[]): RegionLink[] | null {
    let regionSlug: RegionKey | undefined;

    if (pathListaSeo.includes('metropolitana')) {
        regionSlug = 'metropolitana';
    } else if (pathListaSeo.includes('valparaiso')) {
        regionSlug = 'valparaiso';
    } else if (pathListaSeo.includes('biobio')) {
        regionSlug = 'biobio';
    }

    return regionSlug ? regionData[regionSlug] : null;
}

getStaticProps
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<ListaSEOType> = async ({ params }) => {
    const { determineRegionSlug } = setupServices();
    const { pathListaSeo } = params as GetStaticPropsParams;
    const computedRegionSlug = determineRegionSlug(pathListaSeo);

ListaSeo
    const ListaSEO: NextPageLayout<InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>> = (props: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
    const { computedRegionSlug } = props;
    return(
{computedRegionSlug && (
                <Prefooter regionContent={computedRegionSlug} />
            )}
)
    

